# Changing default DRF route patterns

Tags: python, url, django-rest-framework

My models.py looks like

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticleType,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='articles'
    )

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Article Title'
    )
```

And urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('article', ArticleViewSet, basename='article')
urlpatterns = [
    path('viewset/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Now I wan't to list all the Articles with 'article_type=None' and update them by hitting

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewset/article/unmapped
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at [viewset actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Comment: I know about them and I am able to "get" all "unmapped articles" but I am unable to figure out how to add "put" functionality i.e how to update details of any one of them.

Comment: Your viewset action can run any custom code.  So by hitting your `unmapped` URL, you can filter and then update in one operation.  Your question isn't clear on what you want to update with, so if you can clarify your question it will be easier to offer help.

Comment: By hitting 'unmapped' I wan't to list all the articles which have 'article_tyoe = None' and than 'unmapped/<int>" to retrieve the article with 'id=int' and update/put the 'article_type' i.e map it to some article_type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using [ViewSet actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).  The implementation will be along the lines of:

```py
    @action(detail=True, methods=["GET", "PUT"])
    def unmapped(self, request, pk=None):
        if not pk:
            # perform list operation
            articles = self.queryset.filter(article_type=None)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(articles, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        # map obj to article type
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This uses the ViewSet action feature.  If you need to customize the URL, I expect you will have to write a custom view and map it to the required URL in `urls.py`.

This will mean that:

- calls to `http://localhost:8000/unmapped/` will execute the 'list' logic
- calls to `http://localhost:8000/<pk>/unmapped/` will execute the update logic

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [@MathewHegarty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713030/12965178) helps but I solved it by

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["GET"], url_path='unmapped')
def unmapped(self, request):
     articles = self.queryset.filter(article_type=None)
     serializer = self.get_serializer(articles, many=True)
     return Response(serializer.data)

@action(detail=True, methods=["GET"], url_path='unmapped')
def ret_map(self, request):
     obj = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
     return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@ret_map.mapping.put
def map(self, request):
     #code for 'PUT'
```